# How do I Dynamically create components in angular for creating folders for user?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular9

How to create routes where a user is able to create folders.
Something similar to google drive

How do I structure the routes ? What is the best way to achieve this ?

Currently using firestore as backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic routes in Angular you can use route params.
A good explanation is here: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/routeparams
For your Use Case you could use something like /folders/:folderId

Comment: This only works for 2 levels right? I was looking for deep nested dynamic routes. Was trying with router.config.push.    But i don't want to reset the route....